# Google Maps API v3: Earliest EVENT to inform me of the bounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Imagine you are going to a web site with an empty cache.

In Google Maps API v3, what's the earliest event that will be triggered to inform me the bounds of the maps on initial load?

In Google Maps v2 it was the 'loaded' event; however, this event is not present in v3 of the API.

Would it be the 'bound_changed' event for v3 of the API?  If not, does some other event exist that get's fired sooner than bound_changed that will allow me to gain access to the current maps bounds?

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to get the bounds of your map on initial load? or when you do something?

Comment: It's not an event, but if the center location and map size is constant you could use hard-coded values.

Comment: I'm struggling to get the v2 API load/loaded event to fire: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682017/google-maps-api-v2-load-event-not-firing would anyone mind giving me example of using that event?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps will load a blank screen if you don't set the center and zoom level.

There is no load event, however when you instantiate the Map object, you can fire an event at this point, if that is what you are looking for.

I think "bounds_changed" is probably your best bet, because that is guaranteed that bounds_changed actually set the proper values, although the following events have been fired in this order.

```
center_changed, zoom_changed, bounds_changed, idle, tilesloaded
```

Still it makes sense that bounds_changed is where you would pick it up, because google sets the center, sets the zoom level, and determines the bounds.