# Google Maps API v2 load() event not firing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm improving the Google Maps API V2 integration in our web app and I'd like my main page to know when Google Maps has finished loading everything so I can then set some markers.

I notice there's a [load() event](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.load) but I can never seem to get it fire.

Here's the code I'm using

```
    if( GBrowserIsCompatible() ) {

        map = new GMap2(container);

        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(INITIAL_LATITUDE,INITIAL_LONGITUDE), INITIAL_ZOOM);

        GEvent.addListener(map, "load", pluginLoaded );
    }
```

...

```
function pluginLoaded() {
    alert( "pluginLoaded" );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `load` event is not firing because it gets triggered soon after you call `setCenter()`, and at that time your event listener is not attached yet. You can see the event being triggered in the following example:

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
   var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
   GEvent.addListener(map, "load", function() {
      alert("Map Loaded");
   });
   map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
}
```

Note that there is no need to listen for the `load` event to start adding markers to the map.